# LDAPsearch with SSL Centos- ldap_start_tls, ldap_bind: Cannot contact LDAP

Tags: centos, php, ldap

I am working on a integrating LDAP authentication with my PHP Project deployed on a Linux platform. I successfully completed the ldapsearch from command line and from php code for NON SSL connection.

When it comes to SSL connection, I am not able to make it work. I am thinking if I can make the ldapsearch work from commandline, dealing with php side won't be a problem. I am using CentOS and below is my search result query pattern - which works for non-SSL request on port 3268 but fails for port 3269 with two errors `ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)` and `ldap_bind: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`. I have searched for this query and it lead me to pages which talk about Kerboros authentication, which I don't want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**SSL**

```
    [Test]$ ldapsearch -x -h ldap.internal.company.com -D "CN=personName,OU=EUS,
            DC=company,DC=com" -p 3269 -b "dc=company,dc=com" 
            samaccountname=personName -Z "/etc/openldap/cacerts/test.cer" 
             -w "<<MyPassword>>"
        ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
        ldap_bind: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

**Non-SSL**

```
       [Test]$ ldapsearch -x -h ldap.internal.company.com -D "CN=personName,
      OU=EUS, DC=company,DC=com" -p 3268 -b "dc=company,dc=com"            
       samaccountname=personName -Z "/etc/openldap/cacerts/test.cer" -w 
          .....
          ...
         //Gives valid output
```

Comment: `-Z` is not followed by your trusted CA. In fact, the trusted CA(s) cannot be set as part of the command. Use either `ldap.conf`,`.ldaprc` or environmental variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things you could try:

in ldap.conf add this:

```
TLS_REQCERT never
```

And in your ldapsearch string:

```
-H ldaps://ldap.internal.company.com:3269
```

Instead of:

```
-h ldap.internal.company.com -p 3269
```

Comment: Thanks Danila! I did have the ldap.conf setting right but the changing the ldapsearch string did the trick.

Comment: I am glad it helped.

Comment: You should not use "TLS_REQCERT never" in production, then you might as well not use SSL/TLS at all as you will not verify and use the server certificate for encryption.