# ldap is working but not ldaps correctly

Tags: linux, ldap, centos7

I'm a little lost with ldapsearch...
I have to configure a cloud with AD authentication.

this is working well

```
 ldapsearch -h server -p 389 -x -D 'admin.test' -w 'xxx' -b 'cn=admin.test,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com'
```

But i want to make some security and so i try ldaps.

This is working :

```
> ldapsearch -H ldaps://server -x -D 'admin.test' -w 'xxx' -b 'cn=admin.test,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com'
```

And this too :

```
> ldapsearch -H ldaps://server:636 -x -D 'admin.test' -w 'xxx' -b 'cn=admin.test,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com'
```

But this doesn't work.

```
ldapsearch -h server -p 636 -x -D 'admin.test' -w 'xxx' -b 'cn=admin.test,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com' -v
ldap_initialize( ldap://srv-dc01.get.com:636 )
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

I don't know what's going on. And the cloud want an URL and not an URI.
**Other question, is it possible to block ldap and let ldaps working?**

OS : Linux CentOS 7 with selinux Enforced
DC is on server 2008 R2.

Thank you very much.
Regards,
Alexandre

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

From [this page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/9.0/html/Administration_Guide/ldap-clients-ssl.html) it appears that

> The fully-qualified domain name is **always required** with the -h option. This prevents man-in-the-middle attacks.

and that:

> Although using the ldaps protocol is supported, it is deprecated.

More, from `man ldapsearch`:

> **-h**: Specify an alternate host on which the ldap server is running. *Deprecated in favor of -H*.

To allow only secure connections, have a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/459718/configure-openldap-with-tls-required), or another easy solution is an iptable rule:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 389 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --destination-port 389  -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i tried with -Z and -ZZ.

```
 ldapsearch -h server -p 636 -x -D 'admin.test' -w 'xxx' -b cn=admin.test,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com' -v -Z
ldap_initialize( ldap://server.domain.com:636 )
ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

With -ZZ, same error message without ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

You're right, this command does not start the good protocol. Is there a way to force this?

Comment: I found someone that had your same problem, but the answer doesn't tell why: http://serverfault.com/questions/506527/ldapsearch-with-ssl-centos-ldap-start-tls-ldap-bind-cannot-contact-ldap Anyway I think you can comment on other's answers